# Gulp : variables outside gulpfile.js?

Tags: javascript, variables, gulp

Is it possible to put my variables outside my `gulpfile.js`? Example, this block to put in `paths.js`:

```
    path = {
    css: 'web/default/css/',
    scss: 'web/default/scss/',
    js: 'web/default/js/',
    images: 'web/default/images/',
    imgDev: 'web/default/imgDev/',
    imgRetina: 'web/default/imgDev/imgRetina/',
    tplSprite: 'web/default/tools/',
    tpl: 'themes/default/templates/',
    versionBrowsers: 'last 2 versions',
    srv: 'http://www.sbd.local/',
    concatJsScripts: [
        'web/default/js/assets/jquery.raty.js',
        'web/default/js/assets/jquery.bxslider.min.js',
        'web/default/js/assets/main.js'
    ]
};
```

and in my `gulpfile.js`, call `path.srv` or `path.js`

Thanks

Comment: You can always `require` your external file and access all variables inside of it when exported correctly.

Comment: Hi @PostCrafter. I don't found an example a external file. Actually I try to make a module exports but don't work.
My paths..js :
`'use strict';

module.exports = function () {
    return function() {
        var web = 'web/default/';
        var theme = 'themes/default/';
        var path = {
            css: web + 'css/',
            js: web + 'js/',
            images: web + 'images/',
            concatJsScripts: [
                'myurl/jquery.raty.js',
                'myurl/main.js'
            ]
        };
    };
};`

Comment: improve the question with block code format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always `require` external files and access all exported object properties

```
// paths.js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  css: 'web/default/css/',
  scss: 'web/default/scss/',
  js: 'web/default/js/',
  images: 'web/default/images/',
  imgDev: 'web/default/imgDev/',
  imgRetina: 'web/default/imgDev/imgRetina/',
  tplSprite: 'web/default/tools/',
  tpl: 'themes/default/templates/',
  versionBrowsers: 'last 2 versions',
  srv: 'http://www.sbd.local/',
  concatJsScripts: [
    'web/default/js/assets/jquery.raty.js',
    'web/default/js/assets/jquery.bxslider.min.js',
    'web/default/js/assets/main.js'
  ]
};


// gulpfile.js
'use strict';
var path = require('./paths.js');

// path to css
var css = path.css;
```

Alternatively you can also define the paths JSON format to make it look more like a configuration file.

```
// paths.json
{
  "css": "web/default/css/",
  "scss": "web/default/scss/",
  "js": "web/default/js/",
  "images": "web/default/images/",
  "imgDev": "web/default/imgDev/",
  "imgRetina": "web/default/imgDev/imgRetina/",
  "tplSprite": "web/default/tools/",
  "tpl": "themes/default/templates/",
  "versionBrowsers": "last 2 versions",
  "srv": "http://www.sbd.local/",
  "concatJsScripts": [
    "web/default/js/assets/jquery.raty.js",
    "web/default/js/assets/jquery.bxslider.min.js",
    "web/default/js/assets/main.js"
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks ! After my last message, I try this but I made a mistake. Thanks a lot PostCrafter !